# How do I dismiss a modal view controller when testing my iOS app with appium

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automated-tests, appium

Hi I am building automated tests for my iOS apps using Intellij / Appium.

In my Xcode iOS app I present an alert to the user as follows:

```
[vc presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This only has an OK button.

Can anyone tell me how to dismiss this in my java test script?
I am using the following code but it does not work:

```
Object alertBoxes = this.driver.findElementsByClassName("UIAAlertView");

if (alertBoxes instanceof ArrayList) {

    WebElement alertBox = (WebElement)((ArrayList)alertBoxes).get(0);

        if (alertBox.isDisplayed()) {

            alertBox.click();
        }
}
```

It may be obvious that I am new to all of this so I hope my problem is understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question, this solution works

```
this.driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

I have no idea why this works and the click does not.
(btw I am using appium 1.6)